# How to create an Ubuntu live iso that does not install os but runs a simple script

Tags: server, 20.04, iso, live-cd

Goal: Create an Ubuntu Server 20.04 bootable ISO that:

- Does not install Ubuntu
- Obtains an IP and network settings via DHCP
- Just runs a bash script after boot
- Drops to a shell once the script has completed

I have used cubic in the past to create custom desktop installers, but I am looking to build an iso that just runs a basic Ubuntu server  with a few custom applications and a script that will run.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The ubuntu installer for 20.04 and above are in a state of flux. They are moving to something called subiqity. I am trying to use packer to create vagrant boxes, but the graphical installer on 21.10 always launches and gets in the way.On 20.04 server things worked

I have ask a question about how the server boots and goes into the install in this forum a couple of days ago and asked user groups the cloud-init IRC channel and a google forum.  I still can't find an good explanation for how the ubuntu server 21.10 boots and runs the graphical installer.

However, this may not solve  your exact problem, but I found this website:

https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/How-To-Make-Ubuntu-Autoinstall-ISO-with-Cloud-init-2213/

It may help you with what you are trying to do. He is making an ISO and cloud-init may be able to help depending on what you are doing.